# How can I calculate numerically an electrical potential distribution from an electric field distribution?

Tags: poisson, electromagnetism

I want to calculate the *unknown* electrical potential **distribution** $\phi(x)$ (notice this is a function of $x$) from a *known* electric field distribution $\boldsymbol{E}(x)$ using the Poisson equation,

$$
-\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial\boldsymbol{E}}{\partial x}
$$

I would like to do this **numerically**, but I am not sure about the procedure I need to follow to get $\phi(x)$.

Because I have numerical data for $\boldsymbol{E}(x)$ I first integrated the Poisson equation once,

$$
\int \frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2} dx = \int \frac{\partial\boldsymbol{E}(x)}{\partial x} dx
$$

to get,
$$
\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x} = -\boldsymbol{E}(x) + C
$$

This would imply that all I need to do to find $\phi(x)$ is to integrate the numerical data I have for $\boldsymbol{E}(x)$. This is easily done using the trapezium rule but it will give a **constant** value, not a distribution! Basically I don't understand how to convert $\boldsymbol{E}(x)$ to $\phi(x)$ numerically, where I have numerical data for $\boldsymbol{E}(x)$. Do you have suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Hi, this is a relatively basic problem in numerics. You consider a discrete version of the Poisson equation, which leads to a linear system of equations. I suggest you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Poisson_equation and then ask any specific questions about this source here.

Comment: @Lagerbaer This is what I have done (although in a slightly modified way). I have implemented a finite-difference which solves the [Poisson equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation) in terms of Electric field (from the charge dist.), $$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial x}=\rho/\epsilon$$ For my application the Poisson equation is only one in a set if 3 coupled equations. The nature of the problem requires I solve it it terms of electric field. But I would also like to convert the result to look at the potential profile. Do you have suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: Are you in one dimension only? Then you can just integrate. You say that that would give you only a constant, but you carelessly omitted the integration limits from your integrals. You start from some reference point $x_0$ and integrate up to the point $x$ you're interested in, $\phi(x) = \int_{x_0}^x E(x') dx'$

Comment: @Lagerbaer I think that could be the answer, a cumulative integration. Could you show me the mathematics behind the equation your wrote?

Comment: That's just the very basics of an integral. Instead of the indefinite integral that you initially used, you use the definite integral from some reference point $x_0$ to the point of interest $x$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral here

Comment: There are several numerical methods, like [Boundary Element Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_element_method) to solve it. You still need to fix the value in some region for the problem being well posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic equation of electrostatic is
$$
\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\varphi
$$
not
$$
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=-\mathbf{E}+C
$$
It follows from a simple principle that the work electric field does when moving a charge from point A to point B *does not* depend on the path between A and B, otherwise, we would have a perpetuum mobile. *Potential* is by definition is amount of this work. Therefore in order to get potential you have to integrate the force electric field creates at a test charge on any path that is *convenient* for you when you move this charge from $\infty$  to the point of interest.

So let's say you have a path that is described by a function $\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)$ such as
$$
\left\|\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right\|=1
$$
In this case
$$
\varphi\left(\mathbf{x}_0\right)=-\int^{\mathbf{x}_0}_\infty\mathbf{E}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{E}$ is know, we want to find $-\nabla\phi = \mathbf{E}$, then like you wrote in the first equation, but rather we have all $x$, $y$, $z$ second partial derivatives. The following expression is obtained by taking divergence on both sides:
$$
-\Delta \phi = -\left(\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}\right) = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}.\tag{1}
$$
The equation you wrote pre-suppose that $\phi$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are both separable, which is not true for general domain (please see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420868/what-kinds-of-pde-cant-be-solved-by-separation-of-variables/421568) to see why the shape of the domain is related to the separability).

Now equation (1) is Poisson equation, for a bounded domain of interest $\Omega$, we can formulate a Neumann boundary value problem:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\Delta \phi &= \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} \quad \text{in }\Omega,
\\
\nabla \phi\cdot \mathbf{n}&= -\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{n}\quad \text{on }\partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}\tag{2}\right.
$$
This equation (2) is well-posed when certain compatibility condition is assumed, then you can use whichever numerical method that suits your needs (finite element, finite differences, finite volume, Fourier, layer potential, etc).